# Drivers / setup for Macbook Pro 11,3 webcam and Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: webcam, macbook

I've not been able to find any documentation on whether or not I should expect to be able to make the webcam work on my Macbook Pro 11,3 with Ubuntu 14.10. Would appreciate guidance.

Comment: Boot the live USB and try it, this is what live usb are for

Comment: I already have 14.10 installed on the iron from the Live CD.

Comment: so does it work ? If not, error message ?

Comment: My system logs say something about a Failed Link with "pciehp 0000:00:1c.0:pcie004" with an Status Code 0x1001 this is maybe related???  Later in this post it says apple changed the PCI location of the webcam in the newer MacBooks (11,3)

Comment: The other error I see is "Failed to set new screen percentage: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_5fpower_5fmanager_5ferror.Code0: gsd-backlight-helper failed: Could not get the maximum value of the backlight: got invalid backlight value from /sys/devices/pnp0/00:03/backlight/gmux_backlight/max_brightness"

Answer (score 3):

I have a MBP 11,3 and there isn't a drive for the webcam yet (as far as I know).  The camera is on the PCI bus and has changed from years past making it a bit more difficult to get working. (Broadcom please help!)

Here is the kernel bug on it:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71131
and Launchpad/Ubuntu bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isight-firmware-tools/+bug/1247476

There is a project started but apparently isn't working yet.
https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie